# Lightweight STL alternative to std::map

Tags: c++, stl, embedded, containers, c++03

I'm writing an application on an embedded system. I need some type of associative container to be able to access a certain pointer based on a string. Currently I'm using maps  (i.e.        `std::map<char*, SomeType*, CustomComparator>`). I'm using char* as the key type, because I'm communicating with other libraries which have to support for std::string and I do not want to keep casting back and forth. 
But i'm running into an unexpected problem. Every instance (i.e. new type) of std::map takes up about 10Kb in the resulting binary (with no optimizations, for debugging purposes). Since I'm limited something around 500Kb of ROM and I'd possibly need a few dozens, this is a pretty significant drawback (I want to do the debugging on the actual hardware, which I can't if the program does not fit). I'd like to be able to access these items in logarithmic time, if possible. I do not want to resort to using arrays and looping through every item till I find the one I'm looking for. Inserts do not have to be fast, since that's done only during startup. Deletes are executed only during shutdown, so they aren't an issue either.

Does anyone have an alternative idea I could use (preferably STL)?
Note: I'm restricted to C++03.

Comment: By every instance of `std::map` do you mean separate instantiation of `std::map` or instance of the same type of `std::map`?

Comment: "Every instance of std::map takes up about 10Kb in the resulting binary". How do you create instances? How do you measure the size?

Comment: It could be worth to install a newer C++11 (cross-) compiler (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) 4.9) and compile with at least `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Og -g3`. Recent C++ compilers have made significant progress!

Comment: @Slava Each new type of std::map (reusing the same type twice is just a few extra bytes)

Comment: @n.m. I check the number of bytes the resulting binary occupies? :)

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch In the embedded world I'm happy I got even to full c++03 (normally only the abomination called Embedded C++ is used)

Comment: Did you consider using a sorted `std::vector` with `std::lower_bound`? Logarithmic access with no overhead. Of cause insertions and deletions become slow.

Comment: I guess you should do an adhoc implementation using an array and sorting the elements. Depending on the size of your mapping even a sequential search will suffice.

Comment: (1) This is only one one answer out of two. I have asked two questions because I need to know answers to both. (2) Are you going to deploy debug-mode executables with no optimizations? If not, don't even measure them, it's totally meaningless.

Comment: @n.m Sorry, by new intances I mean adding a new type, for example std::map<char*, SomeTypeThatWasNeverPresentBefore*, CustomComparator>. The problem is I need to do the debugging on the actual piece of hardware. Which I can't do if the program does not fit on it, so the size is indeed meaningful.

Comment: OK I now see you have answered the first question in another comment. I can only repeat: don't worry, be happy. Most of these 10Kb is debugging information. It is created separately for each new type. It will all disappear in the release exe. If you are still worried, wrap `std::map<char*, void*, CustomComparator>)` in a thin, fully inline, templatized type-safe layer. The debug info should not even be loaded to memory when the program executes, it sits in the file and is only read by the debugger, so your RAM size doesn't matter (the disk size does).

Comment: The first thing I'd do is not key on `char*` (or `string`)

Comment: Worth looking at [*boost flat associative containers*](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.flat_xxx).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obvious solution could be to use `std::map<const char *, void *, CustomComparator>` under the hood and wrap typecasting under template interface with inline functions. That should eliminate generation of different type of `std::map` for every different pointer type.

Comment: Good spot (without anything given for spotting)!

Comment: That's a neat idea. I'm also going to take a look at the boost::flap_map and std::vector with std::lower_bound ideas. I'd upvote them too, if they were answers.